# easymock returning null instead of my value

Tags: easymock

I am not sure why "metric" ends up being null.  I want the method to always return the same value for my test

```
    CountMetric countMetric = new CountMetricStub("count");
    expect(metricManager.getOrCreateCountMetric(anyObject(String.class))).andStubReturn(countMetric);

    CountMetric metric = metricManager.getOrCreateCountMetric("ASDF");

    assertNotNull(metric);
```

any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replay the mock

```
CountMetric countMetric = new CountMetricStub("count");
expect(metricManager.getOrCreateCountMetric(anyObject(String.class))).andStubReturn(countMetric);
EasyMock.replay(metricManager); //Add this line

CountMetric metric = metricManager.getOrCreateCountMetric("ASDF");

assertNotNull(metric);
```

Currently, the `metricManager` is still in record mode which means any calls to its methods just perform default behaviour.

If you have a call to `EasyMock.verify()` in there too (without the call to `replay()`) EasyMock tells you that you can't call verify while in record mode.